# jax rs, java annotion error when adding xmlrootelement import

Tags: java, xml, jax-rs

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

```
@XmlRootElement
```

when I use the import  javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement  I get a error when I include  XmlRootElement error info : cannot find symbol class is this because of dependencies not included or something else

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
   

    @XmlRootElement
```

I expect to have the ability to generate xml classes, and get response.

Comment: Yes, this is a missing dependency problem. You have to be much more specific about your environment and setup to get help. Note that since JDK 11 (IIRC),  java.xml.bind (JAXB) is no longer part of the JDK base, so it needs to be included explicitly. To further complicate matters, JAXB has moved to the jakarta namespace, jakarta.xml.bind.

Comment: ok, perfect i will give this a try i hope this will work without any issues